# Usability: How do I provide & easily deploy a (preferably node.js + MongoDB based) server backend for my users?

Tags: java, node.js, backend, usability, administration

I'm currently planing an application (brainstorming, more or less), designed to be used in small organizations. The app will require syncronization w/ a backend-server, e.g. for user management and some advanced, centralized functionality. This server has to be hosted locally and should be able to run on Linux, Mac and Windows. I haven't decided how I'm going to realize this, mainly I simply don't know which would be the smartest approach.

Technically speaking, a very interessting approach seemed to be node.js + mongoose, connecting to a local MongoDB. But this is where I'm struggeling: How do I ensure that it's easy and convienient for a organization's IT to set this up?

Installing node.js + MongoDB is tedious work and far from standartized and easy. I don't have the ressources to provide a detailled walthrough for every major OS and configuration or do take over the setup myself. Ideally, the local administrator should run some sort of setup on the machine used as server (a "regular" PC running 24/7 should suffice) and have the system up and running, similar to the way some games provide executables for hosting small game-servers for a couple friends (Minecraft, for instance).

I also thought about Java EE, though I haven't dug into an details here. I'm unsure about whether this is really an option.

Many people suggest to outsource the backend (BaaS), e.g. to parse.com or similar services. This is not an option, since it's mandatory that the backend will be hosted locally.

I'm sorry if this question is too unspecific, but unfortunately, I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Use an ORM and just have it work with a number of different database solutions. That way IT can just user whatever is already running. If you want a fully-contained executable you're going to have to make different versions for Windows and Mac if you want to do any OS level stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you advice both from the sysadmin's side and the developers side.

### Sysadmin

Setting up node.js is not a big task. Setting up a MongoDB *correctly* is. But that is not your business as an application vendor, especially not when you are a one man show FOSS project, as I assume. It is an administrators task to set up a database, so let him do it. Just tell them what you need, maybe point out security concerns and any capable sysadmin will do *his job* and set up the environment.

There are some things you underestimate, however.

Applications, especially useful ones, tend to get used. MongoDB has many benefits, but being polite about resources isn't exactly one of them. So running on a surplus PC *may* work in a software development company or visual effects company, where every workstation has big mem, but in an accountant company your application will lack resources quite fast. Do *not* make promises like "will run on your surplus desktop" until you are absolutely, positively sure about it because you did *extensive* load tests to make sure you are right. Any sensible sysadmin will monitor the application anyway and scale resources up when necessary. But when you make such promises and you break them, you loose the single most important factor for software: the users trust. Once you loose it, it is *very* hard to get it back.

### Developer

You really have to decide whether MongoDB is the right tool for the job. As soon as you have relations between your documents, in which the change of of document has to be reflected in others, you have to be **really** careful. Ask yourself if your decision is based on a rational, educated basis. I have seen some projects been implemented with NoSQL databases which would have been way better of with a relational database, just because NoSQL is some sort of everybody's darling.

It is a FAR way from node.js to Java EE. The concepts of Java EE are not necessarily easy to grasp, especially if you have little experience in application development in general and Java.

### The Problem

Without knowing anything about the application, it is very hard to make a suggestion or give you advice. Why exactly has the mongodb to be local? Can't it be done with a VPC? Is it a webapp, desktop app or server app? Can the source ode be disclosed or not? How many concurrent users per installation can be expected? Do you want a modular or monolithic app? What are your communication needs? What is your experience in programming languages? It is all about what you want to accomplish and which services you want to provide with the app.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and to the point: Chef (chef solo for vagrant) + Vagrant.

Vagrant provides a uniform environment that can be as closed to production as you want and Chef provides provisioning for those environments.

This repository is very close to what you want: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost-Vagrant

There are hundreds of thousands of chef recipes to install and configure pretty much anything in the market.